# How to write an expression in an equivalent form without absolute values?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

The question I have in front of me is the very first problem in Trench's Introduction to Real Analysis:

Write the following expression in equivalent form not involving absolute values:

$a+b+|a-b|$

Looking at the provided answer in the back of the book its:

$2\max(a,b)$

In the chapter I can't find any examples with solutions involving the min/max functions, so feel at a complete loss as to how to get to the above answer.

Comment: Either $a\leq b$ or $b\leq a$.

Comment: If your question stems from not understanding the use of the $\max$ function, the input of $\max$ is an ordered set of elements which can be compared, and the output will be the element which is "the largest."  E.g. $\max\{2,-3,7,\pi\} = 7$ and $\max\{5,x\}$ will be $5$ whenever $x\leq 5$ but will be $x$ whenever $x>5$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $a\ge b$ then we can safely say that:$$a+b+|a-b|=a+b+a-b=2a$$If $a\lt b$ then we can safely say that:$$a+b+|a-b|=a+b-(a-b)=a+b-a+b=2b$$Hopefully you reason to the answer from here...

Comment: "Safely" when $a\ge b$ but not when $a<b$? (Just kidding...)

Comment: Corrected my bad English :)

Comment: Actually I would have added one more "safely", not cancelled the one in your post... :-)

Comment: Done - hopefully correctly this time :)

Comment: I just wanted to note that among the other great and correct solutions that may have more votes than this at the time, it was easiest for me to understand the answer when it was presented as simply being two cases, like this.

Answer (score 14):

All you have to do is write down what the absolute value means.

The definition we have is
$$|x|:=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x\ge0\\-x&\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}$$

So now the equation we have means

$$\begin{align}
a+b+|a-b|&=\begin{cases}a+b+a-b&\text{ if }a-b\ge0\\a+b-(a-b)&\text{ if }a-b<0\end{cases}\\
\\&=\begin{cases}2a&\text{ if }a\ge b\\2b&\text{ if }a<b\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Now all that is required is to recognize
$$\max(a,b)=\begin{cases}a&\text{ if }a\ge b\\b&\text{ if }a<b\end{cases}$$
giving you an answer of 
$$a+b+|a-b|=2\max(a,b)$$

Answer (score 3):

$S = a+b+|a-b| = \begin{cases} a+b+a-b, \text{  if a $\geq$ b} \\ a+b-a+b, \text{ if a $<$ b}\end{cases}= \begin{cases} 2a, \text{ if a $\geq$ b} \\ 2b, \text{ if a $<$ b} \end{cases}= 2\text{ max}(a,b)$

Answer (score 2):

Think about it in two cases:

If $a\geq b$ then $|a-b|=a-b$ and then $a+b+|a-b|=a+b+a-b=2a$.

If $b>a$ then $|a-b|=b-a$ and then $a+b+|a-b|=a+b+b-a=2b$.

In either case, the result is $2\max(a,b)$.

Comment: Everything you have said is true.  However, you neglected the case $a = b$.

Answer (score -1):

There is also a trick. $\sqrt{x}$ means normally the positive square root. Thus, we can use $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$:

$$a+b+|a-b|=a+b+\sqrt{(a-b)^2}$$